# Powershell for loop (from c#)

Tags: c#, loops, powershell

I'm moving my c# program over to Powershell, and I'm stuck with trying to convert my for loop I had working. I don't know quiet how to word this, but I require multiple counter variables within my for loop, and I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. I also couldn't find any references online, so I don't know if this is a limitation of Powershell or not.

So, here's what I mean,
in c# I have:

```
  for (int k = 1, file = 1, perFile = 0; k <= splitGroups; k++, file++, perFile += dtotalPerFile){

        }
```

of course the variable names/types don't matter, so my question is how can I reconstruct this into Powershell? Is it possible to use a For loop? or do I need to move to perhaps a do while to achieve the same results.

Comment: You do realize that the `for` loop you're describing does absolutely nothing?

Comment: You do realize that's not the point of the question, there is a nested loop inside of this one, but that is beyond the scope of this question. I'm just looking to figure out how to format this in Powershell

I did state the variable names did NOT matter.

Comment: It might also be worthwhile mentioning what the loop is actually achieving. It might be there's a powershell cmdlet that can do what you're after without translating directly as a for loop

Comment: I do, but I'm wondering if there's a more *PowerShell-idiomatic* way to do what you're describing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell's `for` loop can do this, but the syntax might be a bit awkward.

You need to wrap the multiple statements for each "section" of the `for` loop in `$()`, so it would look something like this:

```
for ( $($k = 1 ; $file = 1 ; $perFile = 0) ; $k -le $splitGroups; $( $k++ ; $file++ ; $perFile += $dtotalPerFile) ) {
    # stuff
}
```

`for` loops do allow newlines instead of semi-colons, and the sub-expressions do too, so you can clean it up a bit:

```
for ( 
    $(
        $k = 1 
        $file = 1
        $perFile = 0
    )
    $k -lt $splitGroups
    $(
        $k++ 
        $file++ 
        $perFile += $dtotalPerFile
    ) 
) {
    # stuff
}
```

Still kind of a mess though.

Working proof of concept (since we don't have your variables):

```
for (
    $(
        $a = 0
        $b = 10
    )
    $a -lt 10
    $(
        $a++
        $b += 10
    )
) {
    "$a~$b"
}
```

Comment: perfect, just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Just for other's reference, change <= to -ile. But other than that, worked perfectly.

Comment: @beatles1235 got the second one, Mathias already graciously changed the first one for me.

Comment: That may get the job done but it sure gets complicated. I think it would have been simpler to define `$file` and `$perfile` before the loop, and drop the `$file++` and `$perfile++` within the scriptblock of the loop rather than nesting subexpressions like that.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yeah I don't know that I'd actually use this, and it's a bit of a hack, but it is the closest analogue to the C# I could come up with.

Comment: This is a stylistic question. In that vein the following will work, bringing it closer to C#: `for (($i=0), ($j=0); $i -lt 3; $i++, $j++){...}`. Almost there. The assignment statements aren't expressions unless you put them in parenthesis. Making them expressions allows the comma to turn them into a list, also an expression, which is what the For loop needs.

Comment: @user2460798 I wasn't able to get it to work with just parentheses, but I didn't try it with commas like that. It might make a good alternate answer.